# Can not create Elasticsearch cluster with version 2.3.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create Elasticsearch cluster (2,3 nodes) with version 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

In some articles said that if all nodes in one network, need to specify same cluster name in all nodes then Elasticsearch itself will discover them and will add to cluster. I did it but with no results.

Could you help me, is this feature works on 2.3.5?

or need to specify:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If Elasticsearch instances are in the same network they can discover each other and form a cluster. You can specify a cluster name as you say. The default discovery port is 9300. So ensure if that port is reachable between nodes.

Specifying is node address is also an option.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html

Comment: Thanks for quick response. implemented configuring with setting hosts by myself. Will check availability of 9300 ports. btw found this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_removed_features.html

Comment: Shame on me that I missed that